# Mobile Menu Not Opening on iPhone (Chrome or Safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, iphone

I've been asked to de-bug a website - the problem is that the mobile menu will not open on iPhone (likely on other mobile devices as well?).

Here's the link: https://fuzionfitness.herokuapp.com/

It works fine on my laptop when I use Chrome and right click / inspect and change the viewport to a mobile size; however, it doesn't work when it's actually a mobile device (iPhone SE on iOS 11 is the one I've replicated the error on).

Any ideas on how to go about debugging this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it’s an iPhone, plug it in to a computer and use Safari’s developer mode. It’s an idea... hopefully it helps.

Comment: you can debug in safari on your desktop with safari's dev tools by connecting your iphone to your desktop

Comment: thanks - I didn't know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 89px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100vw;
    /*overflow-x: hidden;*/
}
```

because your header overflow-x: hidden;